# Clean Install to "upgrade" from 14.04 to 16.04 on Acer (AMD), and going back?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, acer, 16.04

I wish to perform a clean install of 16.04 on my Acer Aspire laptop, which is currently running 14.04 LTS 64-bit. How do I go about this?

Also, can I go back to Trusty Tahr if I don't like Xenial Xerus?

*Info*
3.2 G memory 
AMD A6-1450 APU with Radeon HD Graphics x 4
Gallium 0.4 on AMD KABINI
378.7 GB disk space

Comment: Why don't you try out a Live USB? And read about proposed changes that may affect your graphics? See http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04 for example.

Comment: But I am already using radeon, not fglrx.

Answer (score 1):

Use CloneZilla to perform a complete system backup, install Xenial Xerus and if you don't like it or it doesn't work the way you expected it, then ... try to fix it first ;)

And if it still doesn't work you can use your image created with CloneZilla and restore your system exactly the way it was before.